# Convolution of sign function with itself

Tags: convolution

How can we calculate the convolution of the following function $(M(f))$ with itself $(M(f) * M(f) )$

$$ M(f)=\begin{cases}\operatorname{sgn}(f) \,,~~~|f|\leq 3w \\ 0 \,,~~~|f|>3w \end{cases}$$

where   $$ \operatorname{sgn}(f)= \begin{cases}1 \,, ~~~f>0 \\ 0 \,,~~~f=0 \\ -1 \,,~~~ f<0. \end{cases}$$

Comment: Have you tried multiplying Fourier transforms?

Comment: @J.G. they are the fourier transforms , thats why I didn't use t as the variable. Do you mean , I should do the fourier transform once more to the sgn(t)? If I wanted to calculate this by using the definition of convolution with the integral , how would I do it?